# Introduce bucket-selector or any post-aggregation filtering(like having in sql) into region map elastic-search/kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, maps, kibana, visualization

I have tabular data by districts and days. Each row contains diff between the current and previous days, i.e. relative value.

```
 district |     day    | metric 
----------+------------+--------
 D1       | 2020-04-12 | -11     
 D1       | 2020-04-13 |  40
 D2       | 2020-04-13 |  20     
 D1       | 2020-04-14 |  11         
 D1       | 2020-04-15 | -50
```

I need to visualize this data on Kibana's region map.

So, the *metric* is grouped by *district* and summarized. Here is the ElasticSearch query generated by Kibana:

```
{"aggs": {
    "2": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "district",
        "size": 300,
        "order": {
          "1": "desc"
        }},
      "aggs": {
        "1": {
          "sum": {
            "field": "metric"
          }}}}},
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [{
          "range": {
            "@timestamp": {
              "format": "strict_date_optional_time",
              "gte": "2020-04-12T00:00:00.0Z",
              "lte": "2020-04-16T00:00:00.0Z"
            }}}]}}}
```

Depending on the selected data rage the result will vary. For example, this query selects all data (see @timestamp filter) and metric values for districts **D1** and **D2** will be **-10** and **20**. If I'll change the filter to select data for 12-13 April it will be *-11 + 40* = **29** for **D1** and **20** for **D2**.

In Kibana I need to filter out buckets with negative **sum(metric)** value and show districts only with a positive sum value. I couldn't find any working solution. I've tried

- Kibana's **JSON input** + [Bucket Selector
  Aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-pipeline-bucket-selector-aggregation.html)
  Visual
- Kibana's Vega Graphs, but it seems that it doesn't support region maps.
  I'd like to avoid it as it's quite complicated.
- Build a new index based on the existing ones, but it's not possible as
  a result depends on a date range filter, so I cannot pre-calculate metrics and filter out negatives because I don't know what date range is in advanced

Nothing of this worked for me. I was able to compose a working Elastic Search query that does exactly what I want, but I don't know how to visualize it using the region map:

```
{"aggs": {
    "2": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "district",
        "size": 300,
        "order": {
          "1": "desc"
        }},
      "aggs": {
        "1": {
          "sum": {
            "field": "metric"
          },
          "1_bucket_selector": { -- here is main part, how get it in region map?
            "bucket_selector": {
              "buckets_path": {
                "metricSum": "1"
              },
              "script": "params.metricSum > 0"
            }}}}}}}
```

So, any workaround to achieve what I want?

[Here](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/introduce-bucket-selector-or-any-post-aggregation-filtering-like-having-in-sql-into-region-map-elastic-search-kibana/227687) is a related topic on Kibana forum